# Steam: lost password

Tags: steam

I've lost my steam password, and I was expecting a password reset via email was possible, while instead it *also* asks for the "secret question", which I remember even less than the password itself.

I've opened a ticket more than two days ago and I've not received any answer, is that normal? What can I expect about that?

Comment: It took just one more day, and didn't even require any proof (the email was enough).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tickets take time. Give it up to 3-4 working days. They will probably require a scan of a retail box's serial with the ticket number or another form of verification before resetting anything thought.

Comment: I hope the Humble Indie Bundle will do, since that's the only serial I've got (bought everything else from steam itself...)

Answer (score 6):

A friend recently forgot his Steam password, and the secret question was something along the lines of "What did customer support last reset your passphrase to?". Turns out that this is some kind of placeholder question when you haven't defined a question yourself. The upshot was, after 3 days Valve customer support sent him a link to reset the password to the email registered to the account. No problems - you might just need to wait a bit longer.